# SQL server 2016 Merge Rows in Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I created a pivot table using the following query in SQL Server 2016.

```
WITH PivotData AS
(
select [T_Spec_Char].[ID],
    format([T_Sample].[TimeStamp], 'dd/MM/yyyy') as DT,
    format([T_Sample].[TimeStamp], 'hh:mm:ss') as TM,
    [T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char],
    [T_Spec].[Line],
    cast([T_Sample].[Value] as float) as Val
from [ABC].[dbo].[T_Spec_Char], [ABC].[dbo].[T_Sample], [ABC].[dbo].[T_Spec] 
where [T_Sample].[Spec_Char_ID] = [T_Spec_Char].[ID] and 
    ([T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char] = 'Zone1Temp' or [T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char] = 'Zone2Temp' 
    or [T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char] = 'Zone3Temp') 
    and [T_Sample].[Spec_ID] = [T_Spec].[ID]
group by [T_Spec_Char].[ID], [T_Sample].[TimeStamp], [T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char], 
    [T_Spec].[Line], [T_Sample].[Value]
)

SELECT
    DT,
    TM,
    [Line],
    Zone1Temp, 
    Zone2Temp, 
    Zone3Temp
FROM PivotData
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Val)
    FOR Spec_Char
    IN (Zone1Temp, Zone2Temp, Zone3Temp)
) AS PivotResult
ORDER BY DT, TM
```

The result is shown as below:

```
DT          TM          Line    Zone1Temp  Zone2Temp  Zone3Temp  
07/02/2017  01:21:55    Line2   310        NULL       NULL
07/02/2017  01:21:55    Line2   NULL       330        NULL
07/02/2017  01:21:55    Line2   NULL       NULL       345
07/02/2017  01:51:56    Line2   310        NULL       NULL
07/02/2017  01:51:57    Line2   NULL       330        NULL
07/02/2017  01:51:57    Line2   NULL       NULL       345
07/02/2017  02:21:56    Line2   310        NULL       NULL
07/02/2017  02:21:56    Line2   NULL       330        NULL
07/02/2017  02:21:56    Line2   NULL       NULL       345
07/02/2017  02:51:56    Line2   310        NULL       NULL
07/02/2017  02:51:56    Line2   NULL       330        NULL
07/02/2017  02:51:56    Line2   NULL       NULL       345
07/02/2017  03:21:56    Line2   310        NULL       NULL
07/02/2017  03:21:56    Line2   NULL       330        NULL
07/02/2017  03:21:58    Line2   NULL       NULL       345
07/02/2017  03:51:56    Line2   310        NULL       NULL
07/02/2017  03:51:57    Line2   NULL       330        NULL
07/02/2017  03:51:57    Line2   NULL       NULL       345
```

How would I merge the rows with the same Date and Time, such as the first 3 rows in the query result above, into one row?

@Noxthron. Your query yields the following:

```
DT          TM          Line    Temp
07/02/2017  01:21:55    Line2   310
07/02/2017  01:21:55    Line2   330
07/02/2017  01:21:55    Line2   345
07/02/2017  01:51:56    Line2   310

I would like to be able to see:
DT          TM          Line    Zone1Temp  Zone2Temp  Zone3Temp  
07/02/2017  01:21:55    Line2   310        330        345
```

Comment: Please do not use images to show your data or query results.

Comment: STLDeveloper, image change to list above, thanks.

Comment: .... please, switch from the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) to explicitly listing joins and their conditions.  It makes it much more clear what items belong to what tables (the `WHERE` clause should mostly be used for primary filtering on the table in the initial `FROM` clause, and that's it).  If you group by every column in your `SELECT` you really meant `DISTINCT`, although it's usually better to figure out where the duplicates are coming from and stop that instead.

Comment: Also, can you please update your query with where table references for all the columns?  I have a suspicion you could cut down the number of tables used in the pivot, but it's hard to tell without knowing where the columns come from.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse table references added. Can you provide example on what you mean switch from implicit join to explicit join with condition?

Comment: Something like: `FROM [T_Sample]
JOIN [T_Spec_Char]
  ON [T_Spec_Char].[ID] = [T_Sample].[Spec_Char_Id]
     AND [T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char] IN ('Zone1Temp', 'Zone2Temp', 'Zone3Temp')
JOIN [T_Spec]
  ON [T_Spec].[ID] = [T_Sample].[Spec_ID]` (which ordering is up to you - I just chose the one where the other two tables linked to the one in the `FROM` clause, instead of chaining links down.  Note that the db is going to shuffle things around for its own benefit, so it's more for readability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ID` from the CTE. `PIVOT` is essentially "`GROUP BY` all columns except for the aggregate and the "`FOR` column". Grouping on ID keeps the rows separate.

```
WITH PivotData AS
(
select format([T_Sample].[TimeStamp], 'dd/MM/yyyy') as DT,
    format([T_Sample].[TimeStamp], 'hh:mm:ss') as TM,
    [T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char],
    [T_Spec].[Line],
    cast([T_Sample].[Value] as float) as Val
from [ABC].[dbo].[T_Spec_Char], [ABC].[dbo].[T_Sample], [ABC].[dbo].[T_Spec] 
where [T_Sample].[Spec_Char_ID] = [T_Spec_Char].[ID] and 
    ([T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char] = 'Zone1Temp' or [T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char] = 'Zone2Temp' 
    or [T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char] = 'Zone3Temp') 
    and [T_Sample].[Spec_ID] = [T_Spec].[ID]
group by [T_Spec_Char].[ID], [T_Sample].[TimeStamp], [T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char], 
    [T_Spec].[Line], [T_Sample].[Value]
)

SELECT
    DT,
    TM,
    [Line],
    Zone1Temp, 
    Zone2Temp, 
    Zone3Temp
FROM PivotData
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Val)
    FOR Spec_Char
    IN (Zone1Temp, Zone2Temp, Zone3Temp)
) AS PivotResult
ORDER BY DT, TM
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested but you should use something like this to group those rows:

```
SELECT
    DT,
    TM,
    [Line],
    COALESCE(Zone1Temp, Zone2Temp, Zone3Temp) AS Temp
FROM PivotData
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Val)
    FOR Spec_Char
    IN (Zone1Temp, Zone2Temp, Zone3Temp)
) AS PivotResult
GROUP BY DT, TM, [Line], COALESCE(Zone1Temp, Zone2Temp, Zone3Temp)
ORDER BY DT, TM
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to remove ID from your PivotData cte

```
WITH PivotData AS
(
select -- remove this field [T_Spec_Char].[ID],
    format([T_Sample].[TimeStamp], 'dd/MM/yyyy') as DT,
    format([T_Sample].[TimeStamp], 'hh:mm:ss') as TM,
    [T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char],
    [T_Spec].[Line],
    cast([T_Sample].[Value] as float) as Val
from [ABC].[dbo].[T_Spec_Char], [ABC].[dbo].[T_Sample], [ABC].[dbo].[T_Spec] 
where [T_Sample].[Spec_Char_ID] = [T_Spec_Char].[ID] and 
    ([T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char] = 'Zone1Temp' or [T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char] = 'Zone2Temp' 
    or [T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char] = 'Zone3Temp') 
    and [T_Sample].[Spec_ID] = [T_Spec].[ID]
group by [T_Spec_Char].[ID], [T_Sample].[TimeStamp], [T_Spec_Char].[Spec_Char], 
    [T_Spec].[Line], [T_Sample].[Value]
)

SELECT
    DT,
    TM,
    [Line],
    Zone1Temp, 
    Zone2Temp, 
    Zone3Temp
FROM PivotData
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Val)
    FOR Spec_Char
    IN (Zone1Temp, Zone2Temp, Zone3Temp)
) AS PivotResult
ORDER BY DT, TM
```